finding weights for Zero Vector matching output vector VQA QISKIT
Hello fellow Quantum Computer Scientists,
I'm relatively new to Quantum Computing and Qiskit. The changes in February have somewhat complicated my learning process, so please pardon my beginner questions. 
I've been experimenting with a Variational Quantum Algorithm (VQA) idea. It's more of a conceptual exploration rather than a practical application, as the data encoding could be optimized significantly. The foundation of my experiment is a feature map that initializes my input asn x $|0\rangle
$
def produce_feature_map(n_qbit: int):
    qc = QuantumCircuit(n_qbit)
    qc.reset(range(n_qbit))
    return qcand ended up with 

I also incorporated an ansatz (thanks again @Egretta.Thula!):
ansatz = EvolvedOperatorAnsatz(op_list, reps=n_layers, evolution=SuzukiTrotter(order=2), parameter_prefix='θ')

I'm curious if there's a way to optimize the parameters inherent to the ansatz so that when applied to the starting vector n x $|0\rangle$ it transforms into a desired result vector. As "training data" I would therefore need no information, just the "label" which would be equivalent to the resulting vector. What methods or optimizers would you suggest? The first methods I've come across include:

EstimatorQNN
SamplerQNN
VQR
VQC

It seems they all use a 1D label to compare the output, which is not what I would need.
Thanks in advance, and have a great weekend!
